# SQL Server is unable to connect to server , requires the actual server name

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

I buy a cloud vps on [vsp.ag](https://www.vps.ag) , which is ubuntu os and I install sql server 
using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu) .
I can remotely connect from my local PC using IP address of VPS . But I can't configure the distribution.

It said

```
SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 

'v3149'. (Replication.Utilities)
```

What I want to do is synchronization my local database and the database on vps using merge replication .
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Replication requires the actual server/instance name of the server. That is, you cannot connect to a DNS alias or IP. Try connecting to the server name listed when you query SELECT @@servername.

Comment: Yes , when I use the server name , it said `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`

Comment: Are you sure Merge Replication is supported with Linux edition?

Comment: @ErikEJ I believe you are correct. Replication is not supported yet according to the current release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes

Answer (score 2):

According to [Release notes for SQL Server vNext on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes), under the section **Unsupported features and services**, Replication is not currently supported.